# Compilng libgcc xgcc error

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, libgcc

I'm trying to install cross compiler, [this tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler), and when I want to make libgcc I just put `make all-target-libgcc`
in my terminal. This make throws error

```
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for i586-elf-gcc...  /usr/src/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/usr/src/build-gcc/./gcc/         -B/usr/local/cross/i586-elf/bin/ -B/usr/local/cross/i586-elf/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/cross/i586-elf/include -isystem /usr/local/cross/i586-elf/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/usr/src/build-gcc/i586-elf/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
```

In config.log I found

```
Target: i586-elf
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.0/configure --target=i586-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --        disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers : (reconfigured) ../gcc-4.8.0/configure --target=i586-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers : (reconfigured) ../gcc-4.8.0/configure --target=i586-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.8.0 (GCC) 
configure:3358: $? = 0
configure:3347:  /usr/src/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/usr/src/build-gcc/./gcc/ -    B/usr/local/cross/i586-elf/bin/ -B/usr/local/cross/i586-elf/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/cross/i586-elf/include -isystem /usr/local/cross/i586-elf/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
```

In fact xgcc don't have '-V' option. I'm searching the way how to compile libgcc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally `libgcc` is part of the GCC compiler so should be built with GCC. You don't need special actions to get it built.

Comment: Same error here. gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the problem:  Before you attempted to build `libgcc` as you described, you built an extreme bare-bones cross compiler.  Now, part of the standard tests that the configure script runs is to test the compiler to see if it will produce a working executable file under normal conditions.  Your bare bones compiler can't.  Fortunately, for `libgcc`, you don't need to produce an executable, just a static library `libgcc.a` .  The problem is that the stupid GNU `autoconf`-generated script doesn't realize that.

I encountered this same problem and devised a very ugly workaround.  You need to comment out a section of the libgcc/configure file in your gcc source directory.  Here's the section I commented out for my version; do something similar to yours:

At line 3484:

```
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $ac_file" >&5
$as_echo "$ac_file" >&6; }
# BEGIN PHILLIP EDIT
# if test -z "$ac_file"; then :
  # $as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
# sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

# { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
# $as_echo "$as_me: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
# { as_fn_set_status 77
# as_fn_error "C compiler cannot create executables
# See \`config.log' for more details." "$LINENO" 5; }; }
# fi
ac_file='a.out'
# END PHILLIP EDIT
ac_exeext=$ac_cv_exeext
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried several version of GCC, it's always the same. Your answer seems to be the only one that solves my problem.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem trying to build libstdc++ by itself.  The configuration options `--enable-offload-target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` resolve the issue and `--disable-bootstrap` saved quite a bit of compile time.  After adding the former flag, `make all-target-libstdc++-v3` stopped complaining about xgcc and the compiler cannot create executables.  No need for the above patch, hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the following section in the `libgcc/configure` file solved it for me. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245344/8138184 for more context on the configure file.

```
# for ac_option in --version -v -V -qversion; do
#   { { ac_try="$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5"
# case "(($ac_try" in
#   *\"* | *\`* | *\\*) ac_try_echo=\$ac_try;;
#   *) ac_try_echo=$ac_try;;
# esac
# eval ac_try_echo="\"\$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: $ac_try_echo\""
# $as_echo "$ac_try_echo"; } >&5
#   (eval "$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5") 2>conftest.err
#   ac_status=$?
#   if test -s conftest.err; then
#     sed '10a\
# ... rest of stderr output deleted ...
#          10q' conftest.err >conftest.er1
#     cat conftest.er1 >&5
#     rm -f conftest.er1 conftest.err
#   fi
#   $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
#   test $ac_status = 0; }
# done
```