# Compilation errors for gcc 6.2

Tags: gcc

I have CentOS 7.2 1511 (gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)), and have been trying to compile gcc 6.2.0 as downloaded from gnu website.   The following is the error I got:

```
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... /home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And looking into the x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc/config.log file:

```
configure:3435: /home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3446: $? = 1
configure:3435: /home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/xxx/gcc-6.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

What is happening here?   I followed the procedure to "mkdir build;cd build" and then issued the configure command as below:

```
../configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-system-zlib --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilng libgcc xgcc error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076660/compilng-libgcc-xgcc-error)

Comment: no, not really.   as you are see, my errors are "-V", -qversion, and even after modifying the configure, there are other errors arising from beyond line number 3600++.   Let me solve the error in the same spirit of Philip's method.

Comment: The errors in configure are meant to happen, that's how configure works, it tries things until it figures out what works. The real issue is probably later in config.log.

Comment: you are right.  I am just lazy wanting to see all the "error" going away in the config.log file soonest.

Answer (score 0):

With slight variation in error from that of (thanks to Oleksandr Kravchuk):

[Compilng libgcc xgcc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076660/compilng-libgcc-xgcc-error)

here below are my solution:

```
--- tmp/gcc-6.2.0/libgcc/configure  2016-04-11 15:45:35.000000000 -0400
+++ gcc-6.2.0/libgcc/configure  2016-09-25 15:59:21.611181908 -0400
@@ -3426,26 +3426,26 @@ See \`config.log' for more details." "$L
 $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for C compiler version" >&5
 set X $ac_compile
 ac_compiler=$2
-for ac_option in --version -v -V -qversion; do
-  { { ac_try="$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5"
-case "(($ac_try" in
-  *\"* | *\`* | *\\*) ac_try_echo=\$ac_try;;
-  *) ac_try_echo=$ac_try;;
-esac
-eval ac_try_echo="\"\$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: $ac_try_echo\""
-$as_echo "$ac_try_echo"; } >&5
-  (eval "$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5") 2>conftest.err
-  ac_status=$?
-  if test -s conftest.err; then
-    sed '10a\
-... rest of stderr output deleted ...
-         10q' conftest.err >conftest.er1
-    cat conftest.er1 >&5
-    rm -f conftest.er1 conftest.err
-  fi
-  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
-  test $ac_status = 0; }
-done
+#for ac_option in --version -v -V -qversion; do
+#  { { ac_try="$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5"
+#case "(($ac_try" in
+#  *\"* | *\`* | *\\*) ac_try_echo=\$ac_try;;
+#  *) ac_try_echo=$ac_try;;
+#esac
+#eval ac_try_echo="\"\$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: $ac_try_echo\""
+#$as_echo "$ac_try_echo"; } >&5
+#  (eval "$ac_compiler $ac_option >&5") 2>conftest.err
+#  ac_status=$?
+#  if test -s conftest.err; then
+#    sed '10a\
+#... rest of stderr output deleted ...
+#         10q' conftest.err >conftest.er1
+#    cat conftest.er1 >&5
+#    rm -f conftest.er1 conftest.err
+#  fi
+#  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
+#  test $ac_status = 0; }
+#done

 cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
```

So essentially I am just ignoring all the checks for "-qversion", "-V" and more.   Moreover, later in the same configure script will give another "libisl" API not found error.   Since I have I downloaded the libisl source code myself and compiled it to /usr/local/lib  directly before, it seemed the gcc compilation is not picking up the new libraries.

Therefore I added "/usr/local/lib" line into the /etc/ld.so.conf file and did a "sudo ldconfig" thereafter.

Compilation proceeded to completion without error and testing seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the *"[stage1-bubble] Error"* because I wasn't following the [proper procedure](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) for building and installing gcc. For example, I had done *configure* on the source directory.

Here's what worked for building and installing gcc 8.1.0 on CentOS 7:

Some pre-requisites first:

```
yum install gcc-c++
yum install libgcc.i686
yum install glibc-devel.i686
yum install epel-release
yum install lbzip2
yum install wget
yum install flex
```

Download, build and install:

```
wget ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-8.1.0/gcc-8.1.0.tar.xz
tar -xvf gcc-8.1.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-8.1.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-8.1.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-8.1.0 --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j 3
make install
```

On my virtual machine the build takes several hours, even with -j option to take advantage of extra CPU cores.

If there is a build failure, for example a missing dependency, it's a good idea to wipe clean the 'objdir' directory and run `make` again.

By the way, these steps also worked to build more recent code from the [Git repository](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror), obviously with some minor modifications.