# configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, config, aiml

I am trying to `./configure` the `libaiml` library but I get this error message.

```
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables See `config.log' for more details
```

This is the content of `config.log` file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-werror

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = nanopim1
uname -m = armv7l
uname -r = 3.4.113-sun8i
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/lib
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /home/m/depot_tools


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2540: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2608: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2619: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2674: result: yes
configure:2825: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2864: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2871: checking for gawk
configure:2901: result: no
configure:2871: checking for mawk
configure:2887: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2898: result: mawk
configure:2909: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2931: result: yes
configure:2960: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2977: result: yes
configure:3169: checking for g++
configure:3185: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:3196: result: g++
configure:3223: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:3232: g++ --version >&5
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3243: $? = 0
configure:3232: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 
configure:3243: $? = 0
configure:3232: g++ -V >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3243: $? = 1
configure:3232: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3243: $? = 1
configure:3263: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:3285: g++    conftest.cpp  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: BFD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1 internal error, aborting at ../../bfd/elf32-arm.c:14098 in allocate_dynrelocs_for_symbol

/usr/bin/ld: Please report this bug.

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3289: $? = 1
configure:3327: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libaiml"
| #define VERSION "0.9.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3332: error: in `/home/m/libAIML':
configure:3334: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CXX=g++
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='mawk'
CC=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='g++'
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libaiml'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PCRECPP_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
V8_INCLUDE=''
V8_LIBS=''
V8_PATH=''
VERSION='0.9.0'
WERROR_CXXFLAG=''
XML2_LIBS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX='g++'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
has_xml2_config=''
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/m/libAIML/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "libaiml"
#define VERSION "0.9.0"

configure: exit 77
```

How can I find and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that the autoconf generated configure script does tests to see whether things can be built. However, the compiler you are using (arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++) does not support the `-qversion` option, or the `-V` option, so compilation fails in these tests. To avoid this you can hack the configure script, like in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076660/compilng-libgcc-xgcc-error). There may be better ways to solve this.